# Attempt to assign property 'content' of non-object laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller {
    protected $layout   = 'layouts.master';
    

    public function dashboard(){
        $this->layout->content = view('dashboard.index')->withTitle('Dashboard');

    }
}
```

sorry, here I followed the tutorial in laravel 4 and I implemented it at level 5.8 (with references in the document laravel 5.8). in implementation, I get the error message

> "Attempt to assign property 'content' of non-object".

if you wish please help thank you

Comment: You have declared property $layout as a string 'layouts.master' and then you are trying to  access a property on it as if it's an object - hence you get the error. `$this->layout` will have the value - a string - 'layouts.master'.

Comment: the means of defining a layout and its content in this type of way doesn't exist in Laravel 5

Comment: if you are going to use Laravel 5.8 use a tutorial that is using 5.8~

Comment: well, I have a Laravel 4.2 tutorial book with good case studies. and I want to implement it in laravel 5.8. * I still refer to the laravel 5.8 documentation

Comment: I have no problems at * $ layout = 'layouts.master'; *
the problem in 'content'. I'm using Blade Templete, and want to call up the content on the dashboard page

Comment: We understand where the problem is. But if old and new versions have incompatible ways of handling things, then you can't mix them.

Comment: @El_Vanja next, are there any suggestions in calling 'content' to the dashboard?